# How to get to the beginning of a particular line in a file?

Tags: c

When I try to return to the beginning of a line in a file using fseek(), I get an error.

My code is as follows:

```
fseek(inptr, -bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), SEEK_CUR)
```

bi.biwidth is of the type int32_t.

I am getting the following error:

```
runtime error: unsigned integer overflow: 18446744073709551613 * 3 cannot be represented in type 'unsigned long'
```

Now I understand the error, but I do not know how to resolve it. Kindly help.

Also, what other way can this be implemented?

Comment: Make sure you're using signed values in the expression... you'll never get a negative, unsigned value.

Comment: Why do you need minus before bitmap width?

Comment: @yellowantphil bi.biWidth is of type int32_t. `RGBTRIPLE` returns three values of type uint8_t.

Comment: @fukanchik I am at the end of a line in a file, and I need to offset to the beginning.

Comment: What about `fseek(inptr, -(long)(bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)), SEEK_CUR)`?

Comment: if you're reading a text file, using `sizeof` a structure isn't right. You need to know the number of characters you read on the line.

Comment: You need that `-bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)` fit in a `long` (see `man fseek`.  No one can tell you how they fit without knowing what `bi.biWidth` and `RGBTRIPLE` can contain.  Now, I still find the fact that the error is an **unsigned** int overflow strange.  The `long` in the third argument for `fseek` is a signed int.

Comment: You should use `ftell()` before reading the line, and save it in a variable. Then use `fseek()` with that variable to go back to that same position.

Comment: This number is suspicious : 18446744073709551613 in hex it is `0x1999 9999 9999 9999`. I guess you somehow corrupted bi.biWidth or misplaced it to palette region.

Comment: @grochmal ...but `sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)` is unsigned and probably larger than `int32_t`

Comment: @Dmitri - Hmmm... I do not think that `sizeof` of something can be larger than a machine word (int).  `sizeof` would return something that would be the size of something in memory (otherwise it does not makes sense since the program would not start), and all memory should fit inside a machine word.

Comment: @grochmal I've got 64-bit `size_t` and 32-bit `int` on my 64-bit Linux system... `size_t` is usually *at least* as large as `int`, often larger (and is unsigned).

Comment: @grochmal I'm not saying `sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)` gives a value that won't fit in `int`, I'm saying its *type* is unsigned and (probably) larger than `int` and will cause the other value in the expression to be converted accordingly.

Comment: `RGBTRIPLE` had type uint8_t, and `bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)` returned an unsigned long. Hence `-(bi.biWidth * (int)(sizeof(RGBTRIPLE))` gave me the correct value.

Comment: @Saha `sizeof` *anything* gives a `size_t` value (which is unsigned).  The cast to `int` does fix your problem, but whether `RGBTRIPLE` is a signed or unsigned type doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*unsigned* math.

`sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)` has a value of 3 and type of `size_t`, some *unsigned* type.  (`size_t` is `unsigned long` on OP's machine)

`-bi.biWidth` has a value of -3 of some signed type narrower than `size_t`, likely `int`.

When multiplied, the -3 is converted to a `size_t` type with a value of `18446744073709551613u` or `0xfffffffffffffffd`.

This product exceeds `size_t` .

`fseek()` expects a `long`, so use `long` math.

```
fseek(inptr, -bi.biWidth * (long) sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), SEEK_CUR)
```

---

The type of `RGBTRIPLE` is not of issue here.  [@Dmitri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929459/dmitri)